# Kraken.js: using Jade for templates?

Tags: node.js, npm, pug, kraken.js

Anyone have experience with setting up Jade for templates in Kraken.js? Not sure how to integrate it into the config file. Results on Google are now outdated. Would like to also remove all dust links from the config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample app is available at https://github.com/aredridel/womp/tree/jade/

The config file has been simplified, and all i18n and dust-related parts removed from the setup.